# How do I make an app plugin-aware without a separate DLL for the plugin interface?

Tags: .net, plugins, dll, bundle

The traditional procedure to develop a plugin architecture seems to be to create a separate DLL containing only the common interface that all plugins will implement, and make both the core app and the plugins depend on that.

I'm trying to do just the same, but without a separate interface dll. One obvious way is to make all plugins depend on the core app, but that's hardly a pretty solution.

Can you think of prettier solution? Ideally, there wouldn't be a dll bundling the interface; if that's impossible, the it would be pretty cool if a user that doesn't intend to run plugins wouldn't need to download the plugin dll at all. Taht way, only those who run plugins need the interface DLL.

Comment: Hopefully what I mean by "interface dll" is clear; all the sources I've found on the web use three components to build an app with plugins: the core binary, a library containing only the plugin interface, and the plugins (separate DLLs). I'm trying to get rid of the second one. Thanks!

Comment: You can edit your question if you want to clarify something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load the assembly and access its types through Reflection.  There are some examples here: http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/, and I've extracted some of the more interesting ones:

```
Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\Test.dll");
Type calcType = testAssembly.GetType("Test.Calculator");
object calcInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(calcType);

// Get property value
PropertyInfo numberPropertyInfo = calcType.GetProperty("Number");
double value = (double)numberPropertyInfo.GetValue(calcInstance, null);

....

// invoke public instance method: public void Clear()
calcType.InvokeMember("Clear",
     BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
     null, calcInstance, null);
```

You can mandate that plugins are written in certain ways so that you know which classes to instantiate and which methods to call, and so on.  Essentially, an informal interface that is expressed via documentation rather than through code.

Now, this is not a good way to implement a plugin architecture, because you lose a lot of compile-time checking when writing plugins, and generally speaking it's better to take the hit of deploying the extra DLL.

Comment: Thanks =) Somewhat dirty indeed ;) I think I'll follow your advice, and go the DLL way.

Comment: Good option :) You might find that the extra DLL is actually pretty small if it only has interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

You could use MEF and import `System.Object` implementations with metadata (strings) instead of actual interface or defined types.

That being said, it's going to be difficult for the host process to *use* the plugins without a known interface.  Some form of use via reflection would be required, which is going to be very, very ugly.

Personally, I would just include a simple DLL with the interfaces, which can stand alone.  The application can bundle it with the distributions, and the plugins can use it.  The benefits of this far outweigh the extra "cost" of maintaining a small assembly with nothing but interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is via Reflection. You would need to inspect the loaded (plugin) assembly to pull out the method information and call Invoke.

Another way to accomplish this in .NET 4 is via `dynamic`. The dynamic keyword allows you to bypass compile-time type checking so you can call any method you want and it will be bound at run-time.

Both options have performance implications, so you would probably not want to do this if you're going to have a lot of chatter between the host and the plugins.